# Прервать что-либо - это на время или навсегда?

Tags: семантика

Прервать что-либо - это на время или навсегда?

Сравниваем **прерывание** матча из-за дождя, программное **прерывание**, **прерывание** беременности и так далее.

Comment: Вы же сами приводите примеры, что может быть и так и так.

Comment: Вы очень наблюдательны. Я действительно привожу примеры.

Comment: Примеры однозначны и без анализа. Если полностью, то будет отмена матча. А разве можно прервать беременность лишь на какое-то время?

Comment: Не думаю, что вы не можете ответить на свой вопрос самостоятельно. Или вам непременно нужно узнать мое мнение?

Comment: Это риторический вопрос. Просто подчёркиваю однозначность. Лучше приводите примеры, в которых вы действительно сомневаетесь. Программное прерывание - это вообще термин программирования, о котором лучше спросить на соответствующем SE сайте: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Я не буду возражать, если вы там свой риторический вопрос зададите. А здесь, простите, хотелось бы от вас услышать ответ на мой вопрос, а не отвечать на ваши.

Comment: @oleedd ответы давайте, пожалуйста, в ответах.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хм... Я полагаю, что глагол допускает оба толкования.

> 1. что. Резко, внезапно прекратить или приостановить что-л. П. разговор. П. все
>    отношения с кем-л. П. молчание. П. урок. П. ход мыслей.

БТС Кузнецова

Правда тут есть один интересный момент. Кузнецов определяет прервать через прекратить и приостановить. Подразумевается, видимо, что первое это в вашей терминологии - "навсегда", а второе - "на время".

Но если посмотреть что такое прекратить, так в нем заложена та же двусмысленность.

> ПРЕКРАТИТЬ, Положить конец чему-л., прервать что-л. П. разговоры. П. заниматься.
> Зима прекратила их свидания. Старик прекратил всякую помощь сыну.

Да и "приостановить", собственно, не столь уж однозначно.

> Временно остановить, задержать, прекратить.

Видимо, тут нельзя дать формальный однозначный ответ.

> в школе почему так учат, что пре - это "пере", а "при" - неполнота
> действия?!

Вопрос, надо полагать, о соответвии этих установок конкретным глаголам.

Учат потому, что правило такое. Я не задумывался. Но, видимо, на всякое правило нужны какие-то оговорки или комментарии (речь не об исключениях, понятно). С "прекратить" в общем-то понятно, тут именно "пере", просто это "пере" само по себе не несет семантики обязательного прекращения "навсегда". Ну вот любой глагол возьмем с похожим смывслом. "Перекрыть" (воду там или движение). Была вода - нет воды. Будет ли - за рамками семантики приставки. Перекопать (улицу), переобуться - все как-то условно. "Перебить", "пересчитать", "перемерить", "перебежать"  - вот этот уже скорее окончательно, но тут может другое значение этой приставки. Путано, конечно. Но в целом понятно, что ни "пере", ни "пре" не означают навсегда.

А вот приостановить... Тоже, пожалуй неоднозначно. Вроде бы понятно, что это временно - и приставка тому соответствует. Но это, кажется, только в юридической практике "приостановить" означает на какой-то срок. И при этом тоже не предполагает автоматического возобновления по прошествии этого срока. В быту, полагаю, приостановить может быть, как о том и пишет кузнецов, воспринято не как вр**е**менная остановка, но как, например, неполная, по значению - близкое к притормозить "притормозить".

Вот вам еще пример путаницы с пре и при. Преумножить и приумножить. Пытаются исходя из значений приставок вывести что-то типа того, что преумножить - это во много раз больше, чем приумножить, но на самом-то деле в живой речи разница эта совершенно не чувствуется. Дошло даже до того, что "преумножить" не все словари признают.

Comment: А в школе почему так учат, что пре - это "пере", а "при" - неполнота действия?!

Comment: Я в ответ добавлю.

Comment: Ясное дело, что "преумножить" не все словари признают. Ведь именно "пр**и**умножить" выбрано в справочнике Лопатина. Статья на эту тему: https://aif.ru/society/education/preumnozhit_ili_priumnozhit_kak_pravilno

Comment: @oleedd спасибо за ссылку. Давно так не смеялся.

Comment: А что там смешного?

Comment: @oleedd А вы посмотрите на источник. Вам полезно. Бульварная газетенка в которой вещает дама непонятной филологической ориентации. Вытащила дословно два определения у Кузнецова - да скомпоновала их так, что все "с точностью до наоборот" получилось.

Comment: @oleedd [Ссылки в поддержку Вашего комментария.] 1. Мнение "Грамоты": правильно **приумножить**. (http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C) 2. Мнение самого В. В. Лопатина: _Теперь в орфографическом словаре оставлен один только глагол **приумножить**, значение которого – «еще более умножить, сильно увеличить» (но сравним семантическое и, соответственно, орфографическое различение глаголов преуменьшить и приуменьшить, которое сохраняется)._ (https://rus.1sept.ru/article.php?ID=200003501)

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова  - не знаю, чего уж вы там поддерживаете, ибо нет не только спора, но и вообще тезиса, который бы нуждался в поддержке... Но вот "справкино" мнение выдавать за мнение "Грамоты" - как-то не комильфо. "Справка" на самом деле - просто сервис вопросов и ответов, там студенты бедные подрабатывают с первого-второго курса. Уровень авторитетности соответвующий.